# Выбор CMS для сайта недвижимости

Tags: wordpress, cms

Здравствуйте. Нужен совет опытных пользователей, какую CMS выбрать для более-менее сложного сайта недвижимости. Остановил свой выбор на WordPress, хотя это блоговая система но все же я ее неплохо знаю. На сайте будет множетво функций которые нужно будет реализовывать самому, например поднятие объявления, премиум объявления, поиск по определенному полю, а так же выбор региона и так далее... Так подскажите же какая CMS подойдет для этого лучше всего, и возможно ли выполнить такое без особых усилий на WordPress?

Comment: "для более-менее сложного сайта недвижимости", мнится мне, стоит писать специально под него заточенную систему.

Comment: Хм, возможно. Но больше половины необходимых функций дает полуизученная WP.

Comment: А не проще будет использовать уже готовую CMS доски объявлений?? Чуть-чуть переделать и всё...

Comment: Нашел на мой взгляд неплохой модуль для WordPress. Довольно функциональная доска объявлений, может что-то выйдет из нее.

Comment: euqen, можно и так. Правда WordPress - блоговая система.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Joomla есть несколько компонентов агентств недвижимости с неплохим функционалом и даже с отображением на карте правда почти везде карты от Google
Для Joomanager делал приаязку к Яндекс картам потому что по России покрытие у Яндекс карт лучше если заинтересует могу скинуть эту доработку.

Comment: Да было бы не плохо, скиньте, если не сложно.

Comment: пишите на почту varz62@gmail.com скину

Answer (score 2):

Вордпресс вообще не подходит для этих целей. вам придется слишком много писать для сайта недвижимости (если конечно это будет не просто картинка дома с контактами и ценой)
если нужен будет фильтр по количеству комнат, району, цене и т.д. и т.п. - все придется писать самому.

Думаю, тот же `dle` - больше подходит под эти цели, даже кажется модуль для недвижимости есть под `dle`.

Есть готовые решения зарубежные - но платно и дорого, зато функционал широкий, можно посмотреть к чему стремиться. Название не скажу, забыл (если нужно могу сбросить вечером).

Comment: Посмотрел дома - к сожалению название движка потерялось

Answer (score 1):

Я бы остановил свой взор на CMS 1С-Битрикс. Так как она совмещает в себе и систему управления для которой уже есть решения и универсальный инструмент для разработки проектов почти любой сложности. У нее хорошо расписанное API, да и с безопасностью будет получше. единственное что она платная, тут уже все от вас зависит, готовы вы вложиться или нет.

Comment: Спасибо, нужно подумать.

Comment: Если вдруг будут вопросы, пишите, чем смогу.

Answer (score 1):

Если требуется бесплатная CMS, то рекомендую Joomla. Даже если не найдете соответствующих модулей, то не трудно будет внести изменения в базу данных и дописать код. А вообще, если есть время, то напишите все с "нуля".